# How to import emails from IMAP supporting email provider to Outlook.com?

Tags: import, imap, outlook.com

My current email provider does not support POP or POP3, but does support IMAP.
How to import emails from that web-mail account to Outlook.com?

Comment: Do you want to just import them or do you want to access your other IMAP account through Outlook.com.  If it's the latter, it's not possible, see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29644/outlook-com-with-imap-or-exchange