# Can one still get a free Google Apps Standard account?

Tags: google-workspace

I know there was a workaround that was working a few months ago to get a free Google Apps account for one user, however, when I tried the workaround this morning it didn't seem to be working. Does anyone know if it still works? Do I need to be using English (US)? And if it doesn't work, what provider would you recommend (I only need email and IMAP is important)?

An example set of instructions for the workaround: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/google-app-mail-for-free/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only a couple of days ago the Google App Engine team announced [the free single user accounts were being discontinued](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/jC_K-YlmXhM), negating that workaround.

[Outlook.com](http://outlook.com) is the most prominent competitor that still lets user use a custom domain for free. [Zoho](http://www.zoho.com/) is another one I've seen mentioned, although I've not personally used either.

Comment: Ah bother. What terrible timing. The problem with Outlook is the lack of IMAP. I think I'll just stick with GoDaddy and then just use the IMAP from there. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: That's a very bad news. I remember earlier there were 100 free accounts per domain in GAE.

Comment: For future viewers, [Outlook now has IMAP](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/29668/16377) :-)

Comment: ... but Outlook still no support for catch-all addresses :(