# Is it possible to go back to the free version of Google Apps?

Tags: google-workspace

Is it possible for us to “downgrade” a Google Apps account after we have gone for the paid version? I don't mean during the guarantee period (if there is one).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can one still get a free Google Apps Standard account?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46784/can-one-still-get-a-free-google-apps-standard-account)

Answer (score 1):

If the domain is running the free trial of Google Apps for Work it's possible to downgrade before the trial period ends. After that, it's not possible to downgrade.

**Reference**
[Downgrade to legacy Free edition - Google Apps Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60229?hl=en)